# how to deal with loading in react-bootstrap-table 2

Tags: reactjs, loading, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to implement the loading attribute inside the react-bootstrap-table2  before the data is fetched. however, since I'm just a new in this environment, I faced some difficulties in dealing with it.

this is the code that generates the table:

```
render() {
return (
  <BootstrapTable
    remote
    loading={this.props.loading}
    keyField="id"
    data={this.props.data}
    columns={this.state.stationColumns}
    pagination={paginationFactory()}
    overlay={overlayFactory({
      spinner: true,
      background: "rgba(192,192,192,0.3)"
    })}
  />
);}
```

as is shown above the columns is fixed and initiated in the constructor. the data and loading attribute are filled by the parent component through props one the data is retrieved.

```
<StationTable key="1" loading={(this.props.stationData.length >0)?false:true} data={this.props.stationData} />
```

after implementing this it showed an error

> caught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

I've noticed if the loading attribute is false, it worked normally but if it became dynamic it showed that error.

so, how can I implement the loading attribute dynamically in a correct manner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^1.1.3"
"react-bootstrap-table2-overlay": "^1.0.0"
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"

Comment: "react-dom": "^16.4.2"

Comment: "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"

Answer (score 0):

As I have experience in using this table component, you have right but to make sure it works, please log *this.props.loading* in the render prototype, because I think it's undefined(A normal event in using react ^_^).
Or try to define defaultProps and propTypes like this:

```
static defaultProps = {
  loading: true
}
```

Comment: I just added the log just after the render() and it showed the loading props was assigned to true before through the error

Comment: render() {
    console.log("loading",this.props.loading);
    return (
      <BootstrapTable

Comment: Please remove **pagination** prop then try. If the problem will be fixed! to be sure the problem related to this prop and you should assign the paginationFactory options to solve this.

Comment: remove pagination made nothing. but I noticed the issue started if and only if the data is empty AND the loading attribute is set to true. if the loading attribute is removed or set to false, everything works fine even if no data was there.